# Javascript: get all integer keys and all values in an Array?

Tags: javascript

`Object.keys(obj)` returns an `Array` of strings that are the keys of an object.
But what if the object is an array and I want the list of integer indexes that it has?
Is there a simple way to extract this without having to `parseInt()` them all?

Alternatively, is there a simple way to implement a sort of `Object.values()` to get an `Array` of the values (with normal Array integer keys) from an object?

Comment: Why on earth would you want an array of keys here? Just start at 0 and iterate to `array.length`.

Comment: It may happen that your array is nearly empty (most numeric values are not set), hence one may want to avoid, say, looping up to 1000000 to find the only 32 existing values.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array for():

```
var arr = ["aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc"];
var iArr = [];
for(var i in arr)
{
    iArr[i] = i;
    alert(i+ " > " + arr[i]);
}
alert(iArr.length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Achilleterzo/kfLzD/

Answer (score -1):

According to the [final final final final draft](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) of ES5, it seems that there is nothing like what you are looking for.

I think that all you can do is

```
var numericKeys = Object.keys(myObject).filter(function (key) {
    return parseInt(key, 10).toString() === key;
});
```

Comment: chrome doesn't understand `myObject.keys()`

Comment: Sorry, I was overlooking the fact that `keys` is an attribute of `Object`, not of `Object.prototype`, so it cannot be called as a method. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You are also overlooking the fact that `Object.keys()` returns only strings, even when the key is a number, hence my reference to `parseInt`. Please try to read and understand the question before answering.

Comment: There is no need to be harsh. I have missed the part where you say that the array contains strings, ok. But I have taken the time to browse the spec to check that no method like the one you want exists for arrays. In any case, I will update my answer (but it will not say much more than the question).